# out of shared memory error when doing pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, locking, psql, pg-dump

I have a postgres database with 3 schemas and around 1200 tables. When I try to take a schema only pg_dump of it using the command, `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d my_test_db -s`, I sometimes get error

> ERROR:  out of shared memory 
>   HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction

This case also occurs in a random manner, when I re-run the same query, it works well. Is there any ways to overcome this

Comment: What happened when you followed the advice in the error message and increased `max_locks_per_transaction`?

Comment: I dont think it to be a perfect solution . Because, if I increase to a certain value, in a short time , even that value will be crossed :(

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: To be frank, I dont understand how this problem occurs in a random manner. So I thought so

Comment: to add a point, this failure seems to occur only in recent times. We have also upgraded our postgres version from 9.5 to 9.6.9 recently

Answer (score 5):

`pg_dump` takes share locks on each table it dumps. So you need to configure Postgres to support that many locks It's unclear to me if you have 3 schemas with 1200 tables **each** - which would mean a total of 3600 tables, or if there are 1200 table distributed across 3 schemas.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-MAX-LOCKS-PER-TRANSACTION)

> The shared lock table tracks locks on `max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)` objects (e.g., tables); hence, no more than this many distinct objects can be locked at any one time. This parameter controls the average number of object locks allocated for each transaction; individual transactions can lock more objects as long as the locks of all transactions fit in the lock table

Assuming everything is configured as the defaults, you wind up with `64 * (100 + 0) = 6400` objects that can be locked. If `pg_dump` is the only thing running on your database the default configuration should be fine.

The fact that you only *occasionally* get that error, means that you have concurrent transactions that also use many object locks so that `pg_dump` can't allocate enough locks.

You should increase that value nonetheless to avoid the "occasional" errors. I would start with increasing it to 128.

Comment: I meant 1200 tables spread across 3 schemas. Also, the scope of the database is : I create a database, apply sql from an archive which creates the tables and schemas, then take dump of it in a SQL file, pass the dump file to another tool which included no database operations. So this is not a concurrent environment

Comment: to add a point, I apply sql from archive using a single transaction